# Why is the second season of Altered Carbon based on the third book rather than the second?

Tags: altered-carbon

I am currently watching *Altered Carbon* on Netflix, which is based on a book trilogy.

The story of the first season by and large follows the storyline of the [first book, *Altered Carbon*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altered_Carbon) (despite a couple of radical changes when it comes to the characters' background and relationships).

Now that I've started watching the second season, I am surprised to notice it seems to be slightly modelled after the [*third* book, *Woken Furies*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woken_Furies) rather than the [second one, *Broken Angels*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_Angels_(novel)).

> At least based on being set on Harlan's World and dealing with Quellcrist Falconer's return.

*Editorial: What a shock! The precious second novel! IMHO the most interesting one in the trilogy, because it contained more info about the mysterious Martians than the other books if I recall correctly, and because it provided for quite a change of scenery (a warzone and a spaceship, rather than just a crime-ridden megacity all the time).*

**Have there been any statements by the producers on why the second novel was not adapted into the series and we skipped right to something vaguely reminiscent of the third book instead?**

Comment: Can I cynically say that you gave yourself your answer in your question?  "a warzone and a spaceship, rather than just a crime-ridden megacity"  What's cheaper to film?

Comment: @DavidW: It's actually my suspicion that this was a major reason, but I'm looking for things like comic-con proclamations, interviews, or other behind-the-scenes statements.